# MS Graph API Subscription for Mail Send

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am wondering if there is a way to create a subscription for the MS Graph API which will send a notification every time a message is send by a user ? If so how would i do that ? Would i subscribe to the send folder on create or is there another way. Currently i have subscription for new emails which works but i have a need for send ones as well.
The documentation does not mention anything specific for the send subscription

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: are you asking about ms graph notification when user creating emails?

Comment: When user sends an email and it is created in the send folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to **created** change type in the **sent items** folder. However there are some cases where emails can be sent without creating a message in sent items.
Resource would look like this

```
me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages
```

Comment: Do you know under which condition this would be the case ?

Comment: Mostly the client settings I think. There used to be an option not to create sent items when sending an email. Also the API to send mails has a boolean option for that. So if another app is sending emails for the users and setting this to false, you might not have it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body

Comment: I am not sure if it will work via ('sent items') as i was able to make it work via me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages also in API docs of Microsoft for known Folders it refers to SentItems and not send items